# Link CSS file in blade file?

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5

How can I properly link my css file in my blade file? I tried `<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "navigation.css">` but didn't work for me. I created a child page that contains navigation bar also a css file within in the same folder. So they're located under (partials) folder sub-folder of templates.

**navigation.blade.php**

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href= "{{ URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">

<div class = "navbar navbar-default">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href = "#">Login</a>
        <a href = "#">Register</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**navigation.css**

```
.navbar-default
{
background-color: #7574bf;
}
```

Bootstrap library.
[image: SSH]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another `<link>` to your stylesheet. That will get your css file. (if it's on the same directory as `bootstrap.min.css` this will works)

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href= "{{ URL::asset('css/navigation.css')}}">
```

So your code will be:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href= "{{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href= "{{ URL::asset('css/navigation.css')}}">

<div class = "navbar navbar-default">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href = "#">Login</a>
        <a href = "#">Register</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Your folder structure:

```
public/css
public/images
public/fonts
public/js
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Didn't work. How can I link properly if they are within the same folder?

Comment: @Francisunoxx can you open you 'developer console' in the browser and see if there are some errors (like 404 not found)?

Comment: It says `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @Francisunoxx is the file located at the `/public` folder or somewhere else?

Comment: My bootstrap file located at `resources/assets/` is this correct?

Comment: You need to place the `css` files in the `/public` folder. See my post, I edited it.

Comment: Am I correct? Should I move my css files that contains bootstrap library in public folder or my customized css?

Comment: You need to move your css files (like `bootstrap.min.css` and `navigation.css`) to the `/public/css` folder.

Comment: Please see my updated post. I run it but the Console says: `GET http://localhost:8000/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css `
`GET http://localhost:8000/assets/css/navigation.css `

Comment: Yes, that's good. That's an apache console which will log all the files that are requested.

Comment: It's already working bro. Appreciated your time. But how can I call `navigation.css` from another file? Am I doing this properly? Or should I put inside `css` folder?

Comment: I think the best way is to put it inside the `css` folder.